# Linux expand LVM into unallocated space

Tags: linux, partitioning, lvm

I have extended the disk space of a linux VM, and I'd like to be able to use that new unallocated space. There are two partitions on my disk so far, the first one has a boot flag, and the second one has a lvm flag, and then there's free space. How can I achieve that from CLI ?

```
> lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0               2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda               8:0    0   15G  0 disk               <---- available space
├─sda1            8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0  7.5G  0 part
  ├─centos-root 253:0    0  6.7G  0 lvm  /             <---- partition to extend
  └─centos-swap 253:1    0  820M  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to create a partition using fdisk (or any other partitioning tool you're comfortable with) in that free space:

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

then type **n** for a new partition, then Return to accept all defaults, then once you're back at the fdisk prompt type **w** to write the changes. We'll assume that the created partition is `/dev/sda3`. Exit fdisk.

Then you tell Linux that you want to use that partition with LVM:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda3
```

and you add that Physical Volume to the existing Volume Group:

```
vgextend centos /dev/sda3
```

Now you can extend the root partition (i.e. the Logical Volume `centos-root`) and the underlying filesystem using all the available space:

```
lvextend -r -l +100%FREE /dev/centos/root
```

Done.

Comment: Since the unallocated space is adjacent to the sda2 partition, is it not possible to extend the existing sda2 partition rather than creating a new one, which would confuse other users as to why there are various partitions for no apparent reason ? If it's possible, please tell me how, and in the event this is not possible, please tell me how I can create that partition using fdisk.

Comment: Is it possible but if you do something wrong you'll end up thrashing your whole filesystem. Creating a new partition instead of messing up with an existing one is much easier and safer. I've changed my answer to explain how to use fdisk.

Comment: I tried the aforementionned commands but it failed somewhere, I think at the very end (lvextend). What I have now is a /dev/sda3 partition, and when I type pvs I see /dev/sda3 centos lvm2 a-- 7.00g 7.00g. However the lvextend command returned "Couldn't create temporary archive name. Volume group "centos" metadata archive failed." The vgextend had a similar output, but seemed to work anyway: " Couldn't create temporary text file name. Backup of volume group centos metadata failed. Volume group "centos" successfully extended"

Comment: I think it is at least in part related to the fact that there is really no space left, and increasing the space requires to modify some files